# Scala: Shapeless Generic with universal traits

Tags: scala, traits, shapeless

I am trying to get hold of a shapeless Generic for a case class with a marker trait, like this:

```
case class X(a:String)

trait UniversalTrait extends Any {}

object MyApp extends App {
  val ok = Generic[X]
  val notOk = Generic[X with UniversalTrait]
}
```

It doesn't compile, with error `could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[X with UniversalTrait]` in the `notOk` line. Why is that? And can something be done?

Side note: I thought that it might be something to do with `from` not being able to add the marker trait to the returned instance, so I attempted fixing things by adding this:

```
object UniversalTrait {
  implicit def genGeneric[P1<:Product with UniversalTrait,P2<:Product,L<:HList]
                 (implicit constraint: P1 =:= P2 with UniversalTrait,
                           underlying: Generic.Aux[P2,L]): Generic.Aux[P1,L] = new Generic[P1]{
        type Repr=L
        def to(t: P1): Repr = underlying.to(t)
        def from(r: Repr): P1 = underlying.from(r).asInstanceOf[P1]
  }
}
```

However, the error remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deriving works for [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) only.
That is a (sealed) trait and case classes (objects) extending the trait.

```
case class X(a:String) extends UniversalTrait

sealed trait UniversalTrait extends Any {}

val ok = Generic[X]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still puzzled why my attempted fix didn't work though?

Comment: @holbech It didn't work since `X with UniversalTrait` **is not** an algebraic data type (although it **equals** to an algebraic data type, `implicitly[X with UniversalTrait =:= X]` when `case class X(a:String) extends UniversalTrait`). The macro simply doesn't expect such type.

Comment: @holbech If you add `scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"` to build.sbt then you see: `Information:(35, 6) shapeless.this.Generic.materialize is not a valid implicit value for shapeless.Generic.Aux[App8.this.X with App8.this.UniversalTrait,String :: shapeless.HNil] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: App8.this.X with App8.this.UniversalTrait is not a case class, case class-like, a sealed trait or Unit
  the[Generic.Aux[X with UniversalTrait, String :: HNil]]`